# numpy savetxt fails when using file handler

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

On windows 7, with the newest numpy 1.13.3 and PYTHON 3.5, if I have an array called points, with shape m x 6 and dtype of float32. I can save the array to a "foo.txt" file as below:

```
np.savetxt('foo.txt', points, fmt='%f %f %f %d %d %d')
```

but if I run

```
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, points, fmt='%f %f %f %d %d %d')
```

i got the error below:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>   ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py
>   in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer,
>   comments) 1214 try:
>   -> 1215 fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline)) 1216 except TypeError:
>
> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) in () 1 with
>   open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
>   ----> 2 np.savetxt(f, points, fmt='%f %f %f %d %d %d') 3
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py
>   in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer,
>   comments) 1217 raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s')
>   and " 1218 "format specifier ('%s')"
>   -> 1219 % (str(X.dtype), format)) 1220 if len(footer) > 0: 1221 footer = footer.replace('\n', '\n' + comments)
>
> TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float32') and format
>   specifier ('%f %f %f %d %d %d')

Am I missing anything?

Comment: `write() argument must be str, not bytes`, try `open('foo.txt', 'wb')`

Comment: `savetxt` writes bytestrings, so the file needs to be opened accordingly (in Py3).

Comment: @R2RT i think you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour only happens with Python 3, and depends on the version of numpy.

With older versions of numpy (before 1.14.0) the file must be opened with `wb` mode to write bytes with `savetxt`.

With numpy 1.14.0 or later, this issue is resolved. The example in the question works as expected.